# Xcode on Button pressed hide label on separate ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, hide, viewcontroller

I am trying to link a pressed event button to a second viewcontroller in order to hide/remove a label inside a view. I am not sure how to explain but have a look.

[image]

As seen in the picture when button 2 is pressed the main label in the first view is removed or hidden.

I have tried using:

file.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {


    IBOutlet UILabel *LabelToHide;

    IBOutlet UIButton *button2;



}

-(IBAction)unhide:(id)sender;

@end
```

file.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)unhide:(id)sender{



}

- (IBAction)hide:(id)sender{

    LabelToHide.hidden = YES;
    button2.hidden = YES;

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this task with `NSNotification` too

In `ViewController` class write in `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(testMethod:) 
        name:@"Notification_name"
        object:nil];


- (void) testMethod:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // call your hide/unhide method
}
```

In ``` viewController``Pressed ``` class on the click of button

post the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"Notification_name" 
        object:self];
```

May be it will work for you

Comment: should i call this method? - (IBAction)hide:(id)sender{

    LabelToHide.hidden = YES;
    button2.hidden = YES;

}

Comment: yes,
- (void) testMethod:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    
     [self hide:nil];
}

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same

In FirstViewController.m file

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FirstView" sender:self];

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FirstView"]) {
        SecondView *view2 = (SecondView *)segue.destinationViewController;
        view2.labletohide = YES;
    }
}
```

In SecondViewController.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL labletohide;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel label;
```

In SecondViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (labletohide)
        self.label.hidden = YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi there, Thanks. What do you mean for  FirstViewController.m & SecondViewController.h? I have to create 2 different Class for each view?

Comment: As you had shown in the figure, you will be having 2 UIViewController class. I just named one with First & other with second.

Comment: where should I insert your code in FirstViewController.m? it says: Use of undeclared identifier 'prepareForSegue'

Comment: This applies if you are using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing 
make an property of UILabel

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

then import your firstView controller in second view controller's .h file

inilialeses your firstview controller in viewdidload method of second viewcontroller

```
VIewController *vc = [ViewController alloc]init];
```

then put this code in your button action method

```
-(void)buttonActionMethod

{
[vc.label setHidden:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: hi. should I import the firstview controller .h in second view controller's .h using #import "FirstViewController.h"  ??

Comment: also xcode fixed the string like this UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];  is this right?

Comment: here a better explanation of what i need to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617246/xcode-5-ios-7-unlock-levels-when-one-level-is-completed

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below code it may be useful

in ViewController.h file declare as

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "DetailsViewController.h"
   @interface ViewController :<UIViewController>
   DetailsViewController *detailsViewController;
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *next;
   @property(nonatomic,retain) DetailsViewController *detailsViewController;
   -(void)nextbuttonClicked;
```

in ViewController.m  metion the below code in button method

```
    -(void)nextbuttonClicked{

    if (self.detailsViewController == nil)
    {
    self.detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController"
                                  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:
    self.detailsViewController animated:YES];

     self.detailsViewController.label.hidden=YES;
    }
    }
```

Now connect **next** button on Interface Builder to action **nextbuttonClicked** 
Create a Xib file with name DetailsViewController and add label to IBOutlet.Hope this may helpful to you.

Comment: When i declare ViewController.h an error says did you mean UiTableViewController?

Comment: declare it in first ViewController where u placed your **Button2**

Comment: mention your Error.Did u created **DetailsViewController.h** and **DetailsViewController.m** with XIB

Comment: yes I did create but when I add the code in ViewController.h i get " Expected Identifier" Cannot find protocol declaration for " UIViewController"

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController {

DetailsViewController *detailsViewController;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *next;
@property(nonatomic,retain) DetailsViewController *detailsViewController;
-(void)nextbuttonClicked;         //solves the errors Is this fine?

Comment: here a better explanation of what i need to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617246/xcode-5-ios-7-unlock-levels-when-one-level-is-completed