# Xcode 5 - ios 7 - Unlock Levels when one level is completed

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutlet

I have the main viewcontrols with 3 levels (3 x UIButtons) . The first one is visible while the other two are hidden.

The second and third levels are going to be visible just when the previous level is completed.

For example in level 1 when i chose the right question level 2 button became visible and so on.

here an example

[image]

Is there a simple way to achieve this? I am new to xcode and I just cannot figure out how to connect the continue button to unhide the level.

here the link with the project file.

http://salvonostrato.com//ex/xcode5/TESTlevels2.zip

Any help is appreciated

In ViwController.h i have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Levell1ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *level1;

    IBOutlet UIButton *level2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *level3;

}

-(IBAction)unhide:(id)sender;

@end
```

then in ViewControl.m I have implemented

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)unhide:(id)sender{

    level2.hidden = NO;
    level3.hidden = NO;

    }
}



-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender{

    level2.hidden = YES;
    level3.hidden = YES;

    }
}
```

In Livell1ViewControl.h i have called a button

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Levell1ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIButton *nextlevel2;
@end
```

The result does not have any issues however, it crashes when the load.

here the upgraded project

http://salvonostrato.com//ex/xcode5/TESTlevels2.zip

Comment: Have you not implemented any code? Please actual try implementing what you want yourself first then come back and ask a question.

Comment: I downloaded your project and there is not a single line of code added to a built-in template. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Hi there, sorry about this I thought there was a easy way to implement this without code, I have made another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629681/xcode-delegate-unhide-buttons-in-vc1-from-vc2  where I explain my problem with coding .. Hope you can help

Comment: Also, you have fallen into the trap of using segues to back to the home screen. This is wrong. It will eventually cause a memory error and crash the app.

Comment: I would I solve this? I dont think I am using "segue"

Comment: my requirement is that when I click the button in VC2 the hidden Button in VC1 became visible
the result I want to achieve is a Quiz Game there are hidden buttons connected to some levels, when level 1 is finished the button linked to level 2 became visible. here there is what I need to achieve