# Unhide buttons in VC1 from VC2 using delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am trying to Unhide some buttons in a ViewControl using a button in a secondary VC.

On my researches I found out that I have to use a "Delegation action".

I have created two classes named VC1 -> VC2

[image]

VC1.h contains:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value;
@end

@interface VC1 : NSObject <CustomDelegate>



@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonToUnhide;

@end
```

in VC1.m I have implemented the function that unhide the button:

```
#import "VC1.h"

@interface VC1 ()

@end

@implementation VC1

-(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value
{
    [self.buttonToUnhide setHidden:value];

}
```

After this I have added add delegate variable as property in VC2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VC1.h"


@interface VC2 : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<CustomDelegate> delegatePpty;

@end
```

And in the end I called the delegate function in VC2.m

```
#import "VC2.h"


@interface VC2 ()

@end

@implementation VC2


-(void)someAction
{
    [self.delegatePpty hideUnhidebutton:NO];//Call the delegate method to execute
}
```

there are no issue but when I try to launch the project it just crash after loading showing this issue:

[image]

Here the project file:

http://salvonostrato.com//ex/xcode5/TEST2.zip

I am not sure what to do next...
please help.

//EDITED

IT keeps crashing showing:

[image]

Comment: Write the protocol in VC2 first..

Comment: thanks you mean write first @protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value;
        in VC2?

Comment: Yes. and also consider below answer. use UIViewController instead of NSObject

Comment: You may also want to change: [self.delegatePpty hideUnhidebutton:NO]; TO 

if ([self.delegatePpty respondsToSelector:@selector(hideUnhidebutton:)]);
   [self.delegatePpty hideUnhidebutton:NO];

Comment: Changed it I got an issue saying "if statement has empty body"

Comment: If your requirement is just to hide the button, you can pass the `buttontohide` to the VC2 and hide it from VC2.

Comment: HI suresh, I need to UNHIDE the button in VC1 when the button in VC2 is pressed

Answer (score 1):

Your VC1 should extend UIViewController.

```
@interface VC1 : UIViewController <CustomDelegate>
```

Make your connections again in the interface builder after that.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i review your code & i'll changes some things. i'll share this one . please check it

```
Replace @interface VC1 : UIViewController <CustomDelegate> instead of @interface VC1 : NSObject <CustomDelegate>
```

And add a navigation controller in story board like below image
[image]

Now its running perfectly :)

Comment: thanks .. I have tried to change the code and add the NC but now I cannot go in the VC1 oradd buttons

Comment: i feel stupid now, but if i run the project it keeps crashing in my Xcode 5

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonToUnhide; here the crash

Comment: u have to synthesize in your .m file like @synthesize buttonToUnhide; And connect properly in storyboard. i am also facing crash in same point. so please check your connection

Comment: for testing purpose i am adding a UIViewController type class in your story board. And u have to adding a navigation controller in your story board. With navigation controller u can find a UITableview controller. just delete that tableview controller and right click on navigation controller and connect setRootViewcontroller with VC1 and run. :)

Comment: NOw it not crashes, but the button in the VC1 stays hidden. I have connect buttonToUnhide to the hidden button in VC1 but it keeps not unhide

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52594/discussion-between-david-r-and-salvo-nostrato)