# Xcode - Using Delegate and Segue to Unlock button in first ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have this simple project where, when a button on a second `ViewController` (SecondViewController) is pressed a `Delegate` function send a string to the first `ViewController` and Unhide a new button which is not visible.

I have no problem now doing this however, if I add a third view between these to windows the function stops working.

Here what I mean:

[image]

In order to do this I use

**In ViewController.h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
```

In ViewController.m I implemented a Segue function which detected an Identifier and send  the value to second view :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"to2"]) {
        SecondViewController *SecondView = segue.destinationViewController ;
        SecondView.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void)done:(UIButton*)name{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"back to first view, name=%@ ", name);
    level2But.hidden = NO;

}
```

To return to the first window i have created a returnButton in SecondViewController.h:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) done:(UIButton*)returnButton; //variable passed to ViewController

@end


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{


    IBOutlet UIButton *returnButton;
    id delegate; //declare delegate as an object

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


-(IBAction)returnButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

**In SeconViewController.m I have:**

```
-(IBAction)returnButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    [self.delegate done:returnButton];

}
```

This code is working just fine However if I had a third View It stops Working.

[image]

This is not working anymore.

AnySuggestion? Any Help?

This is the project file:

http://goo.gl/3rJOje

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629681/unhide-buttons-in-vc1-from-vc2-using-delegate ?

Comment: Either your new view controller has to keep the delegate and pass it along to what is now the **third** view controller or you could use `NSNotificationCenter` and not worry about how many new controllers were between the first two you created.

Comment: It is complitely a new question.. why it is a duplicate???????? with new codes ---

Comment: Hi Phillip, How could I us NSNotificationCenter in order to don't worry about the middle views?

Comment: Instead of telling the delegate that you're done, post a notification with `returnButton` as the notification object.  Have your first view controller listen for the notification and call the `done:` method in response.

Answer (score 0):

I did checked your code and I could see the self.delegate is nil and hence you are not able to move in SecondViewController.m.

-(IBAction)returnButtonPressed:(id)sender{

```
[self.delegate done:returnButton];
```

}

so make sure you pass the delegate.

Also if you want to know how to pass the data(delegate) then go through the below tutorial :

http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: how to i pass the delegate to the first view?

Comment: First : add story board identifier to the middle view controller and create a delegate property and then in segue first pass the delegate from 1st viewController to 2nd ViewController then from 2nd to SecondViewController. Then it will work .

Comment: I have tried to create  @protocol MiddleViewControllerDelegate <NSObject> And passed it to Segue, I have add an identifirer to it but it won't work

Comment: From the secondview if clicked on the continue button it goes back in the middle view instead of the start ViewController

Comment: send me the modified code .. So that I can check and let you know.
Also did u add the middle viewControllerFile .h and .m?

Comment: Hello I hope you have resolved the issue , if not then let me know.